# IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName Complilation Error in QT

Tags: c++, qt

The below code works fine if I use Visual Studio 2010:

```
IShellFolder *psfParent = NULL;
LPITEMIDLIST pidlSystem = NULL;
HRESULT hr;
QString sPath = "C:\\Users\\guest\\Desktop\\kannden"; // for QT
//wchar_t * path = "C:\\Users\\guest\\Desktop\\kannden"; for windows

hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&psfParent);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
{
hr =psfParent->ParseDisplayName(NULL,NULL, path,0, &pidlSystem,NULL);
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEDIR, SHCNF_IDLIST, pidlSystem, 0);
}
```

But if I run the code in QT 4.7, I gett the error:

> no matching function for call to "IShellFolder::ParseDispalyName(NULL, NULL, QString*,int,ITEMIDLIST**,NULL)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a pointer to `QString` when (I believe) `ParseDisplayName` expects a pointer to `wchar_t`. Try:

```
hr = psfParent->ParseDisplayName(NULL,NULL, &QString::toWCharArray(sPath),0, &pidlSystem,NULL);
```

Comment: I tried your code, its giving compilation error, I did some changes and it worked . hr =psfParent->ParseDisplayName(NULL,NULL, (LPOLESTR)path.utf16(),0, &pidlSystem,NULL);  thanks for your help

Comment: sorry, I forgot an '&', maybe this caused your compilation error... I update the answer